# Find index of value in Qlistview

Tags: python, pyside2

I'am using PySide2 and want to search a QListView for a value and have that row selected. Like you can with `.findText(string_to_search_for)` on a QComboBox.
How can i search for a value in a Qlistview and have the index returned?

**some additional info:**

The model of my QListView is implementation of QAbstractTableModel i've written.
The model is filled with data from a database, in the first column the id and 2nd column the name of the Database item. The QListView is only showing the 2nd column. This is my code for the QTableModel.

```
from PySide2 import QtGui,QtCore

class TwoColumnTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, row_data=[], column_data=[], parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.row_data = row_data
        self.column_data = column_data

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.row_data)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.column_data)

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def data(self, index, role):

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:

            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            value = self.row_data[row][column]
            self.dataChanged.emit(row, column, [])
            return value

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:

            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                if section < len(self.column_data):
                    return self.column_data[section]
                else:
                    return "TEMP COL"


    def insertRows(self, position, rows, data=[], parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        self.beginInsertRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)

        for i in range(len(data)):

            columns = []
            row_column1 = data[i][0]
            row_column2 = data[i][1]

            columns.insert(0, row_column1)
            columns.insert(1, row_column2)

            self.row_data.insert(position, columns)

        self.endInsertRows()

        return True

    def removeRows(self, position, rows, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        self.beginRemoveRows()

        for i in range(rows):
            value = self.row_data[position]
            self.row_data.remove(value)
        self.endRemoveRows()

        return True
```

Comment: QListView - is a "view" class, that displays data, taken from some "model" class, extending QAbstractItemModel. What kind of model are you using to feed your view with data? The find method should be implemented in the model class, that you are using.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @MihanEntalpo i'm using a QTableModel, i've edited my post to include the code.

Comment: @eyllanesc I've included it in my post now.

Comment: PySide2 is different to PyQt5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating the following function in QTableModel class:

```
def find_index_of_value(self, search_string, search_column):

    for index in range(self.rowCount(None)):
        model_index = self.index(index, 1)
        index_value = self.data(model_index, search_column)
        if index_value == search_string:
            return model_index
```

The "search_string" being the string i'm looking for and the "search_column" being the column of the model where i want to search for that string. With the return index i can use the setCurrentIndex(index) on my QListView and that's it.